# Git commits using PBIS Active Directory email, not git-configured email

Tags: linux, git, email, active-directory, command-line-interface

My company desktop machine uses [PBIS](http://www.powerbrokeropen.org/) to make my Active Directory user available on a Linux (Ubuntu) desktop. It seems that Git is using my Active Directory credentials as my email address, even though I'm pretty sure that Git is configured properly. Witness that the email address `FOOBAR\dotan@dotan-tm.foobar.local` is being used, even when I've ostensibly got Git configured to use the address `github-com-2010.04@dotancohen.com`:

```
$ whoami
FOOBAR\dotan

$ cat .git/config | grep email
    email = github-com-2010.04@dotancohen.com

$ echo $GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL

$ echo $GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL

$ git commit --amend -am "Add information for Unity desktop"
[master ed323a1] Add information for Unity desktop
 Author: Dotan Cohen <FOOBAR\dotan@dotan-tm.foobar.local>
 Date: Sun Jan 17 09:29:43 2016 +0200
 1 file changed, 20 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)

$ git config user.email github-com-2010.04@dotancohen.com

$ git commit --amend -am "Add information for Unity desktop"
[master 2a8ed96] Add information for Unity desktop
 Author: Dotan Cohen <FOOBAR\dotan@dotan-tm.foobar.local>
 Date: Sun Jan 17 09:29:43 2016 +0200
 1 file changed, 20 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)

$ git config --global user.email github-com-2010.04@dotancohen.com
$ export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL='github-com-2010.04@dotancohen.com'
$ export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL='github-com-2010.04@dotancohen.com'

$ echo $GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL
github-com-2010.04@dotancohen.com

$ echo $GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL
github-com-2010.04@dotancohen.com

$ git commit --amend -am "Add information for Unity desktop"
[master b2800f2] Add information for Unity desktop
 Author: Dotan Cohen <FOOBAR\dotan@dotan-tm.foobar.local>
 Date: Sun Jan 17 09:29:43 2016 +0200
 1 file changed, 20 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

**How can I configure Git to use the proper email address for commits?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are amending your commit. Therefore, the old author name is used. To use your new name (and mail address), use `git commit --reset-author`.

Comment: @dotancohen Glad I could help :)